# How can I write the same line into several files in VHDL

Tags: file, copy, line, vhdl

I actually want to write one and the same line to two different textfiles in VHDL.

First i naively tried just to write into two files this way:
`write (v_lineBuffer, v_string);`
`writeline(f_output1, v_lineBuffer);`
`writeline(f_output2, v_lineBuffer);`

until i realized that *v_lineBuffer* is flushed after *writeline()*.

I also tried to just copy the line:
`write(v_lineBuffer1, v_string);`
`v_lineBuffer2 := v_lineBuffer1;`
`writeline(f_output1, v_lineBuffer1);`
`writeline(f_output2, v_lineBuffer2);`

but ModelSim just crashes at my attempt to copy *v_lineBuffer1* to *v_lineBuffer2*

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You still have the string. Simplest way is to call `write` again to refill `v_linebuffer` before the second `writeline` (and its associated flush).

Comment: Why the 2 downvotes and the close vote? This is way above the general level of VHDL and/or Verilog questions on SO.

Comment: Thx @BrianDrummond, that's what I did in the end although i hoped for a "more beautiful" solution with less code lines :) Thanks anyway for answering!

Comment: Agreed. File I/O and especially text file I/O are not beautiful in VHDL. Given what the language is for, that's pretty unimportant, though sometimes annoying. OTOH, VHDL allows beautiful abstractions. So wrap those ugly lines in a procedure and hide it in a package; anything using the package will look (and be) better for it.

Answer (score 5):

The line type in VHDL is a so-called access type, which corresponds to pointers in other languages. If you want to copy the content one line variable is pointing to to another one, use

```
v_lineBuffer2 := new string'(v_lineBuffer1.all);
```